# Cordova plugins not working when using Framework7

Tags: javascript, cordova, plugins, html-framework-7

I am making a Cordova app using Framework7 for iOS/Android. I'm trying to add the [social sharing plugin](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin) and the [barcode scanner plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner) but the plugin functions can not be called. However when I made a Cordova app with plain HTML and JS (without Framework7) the plugins would work. Is there anything I have to modify on the Framework7 side to enable these Cordova plugins to work?

Comment: Did you referred cordova.js in your html file pointing to right path? Any error trace?

Comment: @Gandhi That worked! I thought I didn't need cordova.js in the beginning so I deleted it. cordova.js isn't in my root directory but is somehow being called allowing the plugin to work. Could you please explain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

cordova.js file need not be there in your project root directory. Everytime you do a particular platform build, it gets automatically created in the platform build's project root directory.

For instance, if you build android platform using 'cordova build android' command, the cordova.js file will be generated under 'platforms\android\assets\www' folder. This js file is very much required to use any of the cordova plugins as it is the one which is responsible for triggering 'onDeviceReady' event once the cordova is ready and all plugins are loaded. You can also have a look at the generated file once to get more info on the same. Hope it helps.