# How to add and work with Cordova plugins

Tags: javascript, cordova

How I can add plugins in my Cordova app? I can't find any examples. I'm trying to install and add plugins in nodejs prompt: `npm i PLUGIN_NAME` and `cordova plugin add PLUGIN_NAME`. After that, I'm trying to write a code for this plugin in my `index.html` file in tag `<script></script>` and I have many errors in console like that: `Uncaught ReferenceError: cordova is not defined(…)` or another. I did read many documentation about that and I know that I need to add any records about plugins to config.xml file. But how I can do it? Can you help me with this trouble?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add plugin, use the following command:

> cordova plugin add PLUGIN_NAME

Once the plugin is added, to invoke the plugin code, register deviceready event in your code and invoke the plugin code inside the device ready event listener. Also ensure to include cordova.js file in your HTML which will give 404 error on development but will included once you build your android or browser platform and it will be available during the execution.

Check out this [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36973472/cordova-plugins-not-working-when-using-framework7/36996031#36996031) for more info on this. You can also check out this [sample cordova app](https://github.com/gandhirajan/Cordova_Local_Notification) which uses local notification plugin as a reference for plugin invocation

Answer (score 0):

You need to add reference to cordova.js in your index.html file like following,

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
```

This can appear in head section or at bottom in body section. But refer it before any other js references.

Comment: I'm already trying that and have a error in console like "File cordova.js not found"

Comment: you are testing in browser, emulator Or device?

Comment: browser and device

Comment: browser cannot detect the cordova.js as it is added while creating apk. Also, this will only work when you build the code with cordova build command. You can use bundled apk in you device. You can not directly browser the html. Cordova won't work that way.

Comment: I have a *.html files of my app in folder "/www/pages". Maybe something wrong with it?

Comment: @AshokM.Prajapati Browser of course detects cordova.js provided the browser platform is added properly